# Multilingual spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, multilingual

I need to make a spreadsheet template that needs to be support both English and Spanish.
I know **Office 2010** has an option to translate content into desired language but its a manual process.
Is there a way to allow the user to select the language when he opens the template , and automatically translate the content into target language ?
Or will I need to make two copies of the template ?

For those who are going to comment that Bing and Google do not do a very good job of translating , I don't have any content that is going to be lost in translation.